# Iterate over a list of autobox type in Java

Tags: java, iteration

If I populate a list like this

```java
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            l.add(i);
        }
```

What is the best way to iterate over this list (in term of code cleanliness and efficiency) :

With the autobox type

```java
        for(Integer i : l) {
            // do stuff...
        }
```

or with the primitive type

```java
        for(int i : l) {
            // do stuff...
        }
```

Comment: To me it would depend on what you need `i` for inside the loop. If you need an `int`, declare it an `int`. If you need an `Integer`, declare it an `Integer`. If you need both, I’d tend to go towards `Integer`, but it would depend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the first loop - `for(Integer i : l)`  - has no auto-boxing, since `l` is a `List<Integer>`. The auto-boxing takes place when you add the elements to that `List`.

On the other hand, the second loop - `for(int i : l)` - has auto-unboxing of the `Integer` elements to `int`s.

As to which one is better, it depends on what you are going to do with the elements.

If, for example, you are going to add them to another `List` (or check if they are keys of some `Map`), there's no need to unbox them, so you can use the first loop.

If, one the other hand, you're going to do numeric operations on them (such as computing their sum), you'll have to unbox them anyway, so you might as well go with the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

i tried the both option for calculate the sum of the list and ths is the result
[image]